# When taking a sample of a population with clusters, how do we set a threshold so that the clusters are significant?

Tags: clustering, sampling

For example, say we have a population of about 200,000 datapoints which can be sorted into about 10 clusters. However, performing the clustering process on the entire population is not feasible. Thus we need to take a sample size and perform clustering on that. In this sample, once we perform the necessary clustering (using a method like HDBSCAN for example), our sample would have about 20,000 datapoints each sorted into 1 of 10 clusters. However, at what point do these clusters become insignificant? Say the distribution of clusters is as such :

| Cluster ID | Size of Cluster in Sample |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 |
| 2 | 2000 |
| 3 | 1500 |
| 4 | 1000 |
| 5 | 500 |
| 6 | 200 |
| 7 | 150 |
| 8 | 100 |
| 9 | 30 |
| 10 | 20 |

There is a clear dropoff as the clusters become smaller, and especially once the size of the cluster reaches double digits it would seem as if the clusters' representation of the population deviates further and further. At what point exactly do we set the necessary threshold for cluster size so that the cluster can be considered significant, AND the sample is still representative of the population?

Comment: So your question is about small clusters which naturally will tend to vanish, not show up, in a "small" sample. If you know the population of objects or its distributional characteristics, you could answer by simulations. If you don't know the population, there is no way to answer your question. The obvious dialectics is that with a single sample, you can't tell for sure whether the object is a "noise/outlier" or it is a representative of a small real cluster.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks for the response. In my case, I do not know the overall population but it is possible for me to take multiple random samples of a specified size (about say 20,000). Given this information, would it be possible for me to define a necessary threshold? My initial approach to tackling this problem was to use Cochran's formula with the necessary parameters, however that is primarily used for determining minimum SAMPLE size, not cluster size. Does that seem alright to you?